# Why does this php code not display my calendar given the year and month?

Tags: php, html

I select the dropdowns and nothing populates. I am not sure why? I am new to php so any help is much appreciated.

here is my code:

```
<section id="content" class="planner">  
<select id="month" name="month">                      
  <option value="0">--Select Month--</option>
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="Februrary">February</option>
  <option value="March">March</option>
  <option value="April">April</option>
  <option value="May">May</option>
  <option value="June">June</option>
  <option value="July">July</option>
  <option value="August">August</option>
  <option value="September">September</option>
  <option value="October">October</option>
  <option value="November">November</option>
  <option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select id="year" name="year">                      
  <option value="0">--Select Year--</option>
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2012">2013</option>
  <option value="2012">2014</option>
  <option value="2012">2015</option>
  <option value="2012">2016</option>
</select>

<table class="month">
    <tr class="days">
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Tues</td>
        <td>Wed</td>
        <td>Thurs</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
        <td>Sat</td>
        <td>Sun</td>
    </tr>
<?php 

        if($_POST['month'] && $_POST['year'] != 0)
        {
           $today = date("d"); // Current day
           $month=$_POST['month'];
           $year=$_POST['year'];
           GenerateCalendar($today,$month,$year);
        }

        function GenerateCalendar($today,$month,$year)
        {
            $today = date("d"); // Current day
            $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year); // Days in current month

            $lastmonth = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$month-1,1,$year)); // Days in previous month

            $start = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)); // Starting day of current month
            $finish = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,$month,$days,$year)); // Finishing day of  current month
            $laststart = $start - 1; // Days of previous month in calander

            $counter = 1;
            $nextMonthCounter = 1;

            if($start > 5){ $rows = 6; }else {$rows = 5; }

            for($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++){
                    echo '<tr class="week">';
                    for($x = 1; $x <= 7; $x++){             

                            if(($counter - $start) < 0){
                                    $date = (($lastmonth - $laststart) + $counter);
                                    $class = 'class="blur"';
                            }else if(($counter - $start) >= $days){
                                    $date = ($nextMonthCounter);
                                    $nextMonthCounter++;

                                    $class = 'class="blur"';

                            }else {
                                    $date = ($counter - $start + 1);
                                    if($today == $counter - $start + 1){
                                            $class = 'class="today"';
                                    }
                            }


                            echo '<td '.$class.'><a class="date">'. $date . '</a></td>';

                            $counter++;
                            $class = '';
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
            }
        }

?>
</table>
</section>
```

Comment: missing html `<form>`

Comment: so put <form> around the select statements?

Comment: learn html then move on to php

Comment: @user977154 I think you're not understanding PHP. PHP runs when the page first loads. I'm assuming you're expecting to select from the dropdown, then expect the PHP to run, but that's not it. If you want to do that, you want to be using javascript

Comment: @kennypu what is the best way for me to do this in PHP while having the dropdowns?

Comment: @user977154 what you have is actually fine, but you need to submit the form to the current page first. surround the dropdowns with `<form action='' method='post'>`, then make sure you have a submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the html `<form>` tags around your select statements. You are also going to need an input type submit to send the form

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="myForm">
    <!--YOUR SELECTS-->
    <input type="submit" value="SEND THIS FORM"/>
</form>
```

the form action"" sends the post data to your current page. The method is either POST or GET. You are using POST.

That's all. You should consider learning HTML basics before continuing onto php.